# Create Solr readonly user

Tags: solr

I want to create a read only user for my Solr-Cloud-Cluster. For this I create a new security.json file an uploaded into me zookeeper server. But the user solr can do selects/inserts, but the SOLRREAD user only insert. I want that the SOLRREAD user can only read a collection, but not write into it.

Solr 5.5.0

Do you know whats wrong?

```
    /usr/iop/4.2.0.0/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost bdmstd001.zit.com:2181 -cmd put /solr/security.json '
{
  "authentication": {
   "blockUnknown": true,
    "class": "solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
    "credentials": {
      "solr": "Some hash",
      "SOLRREAD": "Some hash"
    }
  },
    "":{"v":3},
  "authorization": {
    "class": "solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
    "user-role": {
      "solr": "admin",
     "SOLRREAD" : "dev"
    },
    "permissions": [
      {
        "role": "dev",
        "name": "collection-admin-read",
      },
      {
        "role": "admin",
        "name": "collection-admin-edit",
      }
    ]
  }
}
'
```

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, are you sure you've actually uploaded a valid `security.json` file? (in particular, the `"":{"v":3}},` entry ends the file right there). You can test your file [using a json linter](https://jsonlint.com/). My guess is that you haven't actually enabled authorization at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I remove the invalid Object, but I getting in the same state

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the current state of your security.json file, and check the Solr log for any errors when starting up or trying to authenticate.

Comment: I already updated the security.json

Comment: It's still not valid JSON (trailing commas), but I'm not sure if Solr's parser for security.json will mind. Additionally - if you're editing it manually, you'll have to make sure you're updating the version number as well - _You can edit it manually, but you must take care to remove any version data so it will be properly updated across all ZooKeeper nodes. The version data is found at the end of the security.json file, and will appear as the letter "v" followed by a number, such as {"v":138}._ You might also want to confirm that you have the version tag on the correct level in the JSON file.